# Is using a user's password to encrypt their username a feasible and secure way to allow them to log in to a service?

Tags: security, encryption, passwords

First things first, this is likely a complicated question (I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask this) but I've been thinking of a secure way for a user to log in to a service (for this example we'll go with a website) using a username and a password, while the server itself does not store either of these directly.

I came up with this in a lesson on hashing in school, so I wouldn't be surprised if there's a simple reason as to why this is not used by websites but I haven't found any examples at all of this being used online. This would use a form of asymmetric encryption on the server side to combine the username and password into one unique "userLoginID" that would be stored on the server. Code similar to this would be used on the server side, where "encrypt" would be a one-way encryption function:

```
userLoginID == "331845364410495642424788" # Just an example
if (encrypt(inputtedUsername,inputtedPassword) == userLoginID)
    return True
else
    return False
```

If anyone has any examples of similar processes to this or an explanation as to why it is not used more commonly, that would be great. Using this method, the user would have a different "Display Name" and "User ID" if necessary that they would be referred to by others / the server. I personally can't see any disadvantages to using this system so I would like it if someone with more knowledge in server security could explain a flaw in this type of system.

As far as I can tell, a hacker would have to brute force both the username and the password, and even if they had access to the full list of user login IDs they would not be able to do anything with them, but I'm certain this can't be flawless as I've just come up with it on a whim. Thanks, and I appreciate that this probably isn't the best place or way to ask this.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what benefit your system provides us in terms of security versus traditional password hashing.  Is it just that the username is also unknown to the server?

Comment: Also, just a quick nitpick, encrypt explicitly means a reversible operation.  Saying one-way encryption doesn't really make sense.  I think you meant to use the word "hashing" 

Comment: Well I'm not too sure about how exactly hackers get into stuff but this would mean that if they were to gain access to the user list then the only information they would gain would be their user login ID that would be practically impossible to gain access to their username or password from as they would have to brute force both. Thanks for the clarification on hashing, I just got confused as asymmetric encryption does essentially the same thing but can be reversed with a different key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current standard way to handle this scenario is pretty similar, just without including the username.  When an account is created, the user's password is hashed with a password hashing algorithm (argon2, bcrypt etc.).  This hash is stored alongside the username.  The only difference with your suggestion is that the username is included in this hash.

A lot of the time, keeping the username "secret" isn't a big deal or required.  I'm not saying your that your idea (with some adjustments) wouldn't work, I'm saying it may not be that useful, or would only be useful in specific circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing there is actually [hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) (asymmetric encryption is a weird term tbh) the password using the username as a [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)), which is a quite fine method to prevent table-lookup based attacks, like rainbow tables, online lookup, etc..

It's not a bad method at all if the hash function you use is secure, like SHA-1, but what it's actually recommended today is to use a key derivation function where you do the same hash funcion multiple times to also prevent brute force attacks (or at least make them incredibly harder), see [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) for a pretty good implementation, you could use it with the username+password salt thing too.